# React-native: Why rendering an empty view component creates an error while a text component runs?

Tags: ios, view, nested, react-native

I am trying to create an array of View components in react-native that are passed to a parent component. The code below does not work, however if i use Text instead of View it works. I want use view to show empty or filled circles. I couldn't find the reason for it and i assume it should be possible to use an empty view. What am i doing wrong?

```
class card extends React.Component {

renderScore(balance, fulfill, markImage){
    var scores = [];

    for (i = 1; i <= fulfill; i++) { 
        if(i<=balance){
            if (markImage) {
               scores.push(<View style={styles.emptyCircle} key={i}>  </View>);
               //scores.push(<View style={styles.emptyCircle} key={i}> <Image source={{uri: markImage}} style={styles.markImage}/> </View>);
            }
            else{   
                scores.push(<View style={styles.emptyCircle} key={i}> <View style={styles.punchCircle}></View> </View>);
            }
            }
        else
        {
            scores.push(<View style={styles.emptyCircle} key={i}>  </View>);
        }

    }
    return(scores);
    }

}
```

This will give 'RawText " " must be wrapped in an explicit  component.'

However if use

```
 scores.push(<Text style={styles.emptyCircle} key={i}>  </Text>);
```

it works.

It is called from a ListView as

```
_renderCard(item){
var cardBottom = new cardRenderer();
var childView = cardBottom.renderScore(item.balance, item.fulfill, item.markImage);
console.log(childView);
return(
<View style={styles.mainConatiner}>
  <View style={styles.leftConatiner}>
      <Image
      source={{uri: item.avatarLeft}}
      style={styles.thumbnail}
      />
  </View>

  <View style={styles.rightConatiner}>
      <View style={styles.rightUpConatiner}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.subTitle}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.expires}</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.rightDownConatiner}>{childView}</View>
  </View>
</View>
);
```

}

Comment: so remove the inner spaces, just leave like `<View style={styles.emptyCircle} key={i}></View>`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cherniv, it works!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
return(<View>{scores}</View>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below for empty view

```
return(<></>)
```